# where to store database string connection in java web app?

Tags: java, database, connection-string, database-connection, connection-pooling

I'm about to begin my first project with java

Let me tell how I used to handle these things...

So far now, I've been workin on asp with a com+ componente made with VB6.

The component is registered via the com+ administration console with a domain user, something lile my_company_domain\my_app_account

The components reads the configuration from an udl file, configured to access the DB with integrated security.

I invoke the componente from asp with server.createobject, the component runs with the specified domain account, and so every DB access runs with this account...

What I like from this approach is the following:

- use of integrated security - no sql users
- no need to recompile anything to change db (edit udl file) or domain account (edit com+ component configuration)
- pooled connections (as I'm always using the same connection string)
- production staff can alter the configuration without leaving the account password on a text file

...

well, what would be the best way to achieve something like this on java???

I've already saw something about Commons-DBCP, is it possible to use integrated security with this???

thanks a lot...

--

added in response to a comment

by integrated security I mean I only have to configure a domain account, and that's it, I use no sql server accounts, just the account under which the VB6 com+ component is run.

Ok, maybe that's not the appropiate term, but I hope you get the idea...

Comment: Can you elaborate, what do you mean by integrated security?

Answer (score 7):

1. Configure DataSource & ConnectionPool on app-server side.
2. Obtain DataSource from JNDI environment from your web-application.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this a little please?